# How do I convert a Generic IList<T> to IList?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a `ListCollectionView` with a generic `IList<T>` but the constructor gets a non-generic `IList`.
How can I convert my list from `IList<T>` to `IList`?

if there is another way to create a `ListCollectionView` with a generic `IList<T>` I would like to hear it :)

Comment: Much to my surprise, `IList<T>` doesn't implement `IList`. I assumed it would.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annoyingly, `IList<T>` is one of those interfaces which doesn't implement its non-generic counterpart `IList`.

If you can find a way to pass a `List<T>` rather than an `IList<T>` (or some other type which implements `IList` as well as `IList<T>`, such as `ObservableCollection<T>`), that's going to be easiest. This might mean changing your application so that you pass a `List<T>` or something else around rather than an `IList<T>`.

Otherwise, you might have to create a new `List<T>` using the elements in the `IList<T>`, and pass that (i.e. `myList.ToList()`). Note that this means that you've created a copy of your list, and so changes to the original won't be reflected in the copy. In particular, `ListCollectionView` checks to see whether the source collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, and subscribes to collection changed events if so: this obviously won't work if you create a copy of your list.

Answer (score 4):

`List<T>` implements `IList` (`IList<T>` does not). Create a `List<T>` from your `IList<T>` and pass that to the `ListCollectionView` constructor:

```
ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(new List<YourType>(yourIList));
```

Comment: Since the LINQ method `.ToList()` returns a `List<T>` and since `IList<T>` requires that you also implement `IEnumerable<T>`, it seems like the simplest solution might be simply `yourIList.ToList()` :)

Comment: @John Yeah, that definitely works too. But so does this, so I actually wasn't sure which to pick for my answer...

Comment: :) Indeed. I just felt my contribution wasn't really enough to warrant its own, but complements yours.